# Socket.io in a module

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a chat module using socket.io. Ideally I would like to pass the port number like this:

```
var anotherChatApp = require("anotherChatApp")(1337);
```

the problem I'm having is finding the object after I've set the listen() method.

```
var io = require("socket.io");

function anotherChatApp(port){
    io.listen(port);
}
```

then I don't know where it goes, because I try to access the io object:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //dosomething
}
```

and I get runtime errors:

```
Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

I was loving node until I started building a module.

EDIT:

```
var io = require("socket.io");

function MacroChat(portNo){
    io = require("socket.io").listen(portNo);
}

module.exports = MacroChat;

//here is where the errors come in
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

});
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wamp\www\nodejitsu\macrochat\node_modules\MacroChat\lib\macrochat.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\wamp\www\nodejitsu\macrochat\node_modules\MacroChat\index.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: can you be more specific, what produces the error ? importing the custom module ?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting:

Comment: what are you exporting ? can you give the file structure ? have a look at this  http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

Comment: the error get's thrown when I try to access io from anywhere outside the constructor anotherChatApp.

Comment: updated my original post with code and error.

Comment: thanks. I seem to have gotten it working. I read the link you included made some adjustments and voila. thanks.